# Display custom checkbox field state on WooCommerce thankyou page

Tags: php, wordpress, checkbox, woocommerce, checkout

Based on my previous question + the answer to the question

[How to save from WooCommerce checkout a custom checkbox field state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65447411/how-to-save-from-woocommerce-checkout-a-custom-checkbox-field-state)

I have an additional checkbox on WooCommerce checkout page, but when the order is complete I don't see the additional field on the thankyou page.
My checkbox save value `1` or `0` in `meta_data` when checkbox is checked or unchecked

```
$order->update_meta_data( 'ritiro_sede', $value );
```

I would like to see word `SI` if checkbox is checked and word `NO` if checkbox is unchecked, but this function not work:

Does anyone have any idea what might be wrong?

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'my_custom_checkout_field_display_order_data_ritiro_sede', 10, 1 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_view_order', 'my_custom_checkout_field_display_order_data_ritiro_sede', 10, 1 );
function my_custom_checkout_field_display_order_data_ritiro_sede( $order ){ 
    $ritiro_sede = get_post_meta( $order_id, 'ritiro_sede', true );
    if( $ritiro_sede == 1 )
        echo '<p><strong>Ritiro In sede: </strong> <span style="color:red;">SI</span></p>';
    if( $ritiro_sede == 0 )
        echo '<p><strong>Ritiro In sede: </strong> <span style="color:red;">NO</span></p>';
    //echo '<p>'. __('Ritiro in Sede: ') . get_post_meta($order->get_id(), 'ritiro_sede', true .'</p');
    //echo '<p>'. __('Ritiro in Sede: ','theme_name') . get_value($order->get_the_id(), 'ritiro_sede', true .'</p>');       
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** The first mistake you will make is using `$order` as argument, while this should be the `$order_id`

So this

```php
function my_custom_checkout_field_display_order_data_ritiro_sede( $order ){
```

Becomes

```php
function my_custom_checkout_field_display_order_data_ritiro_sede( $order_id ){
```

---

**2)** The second mistake is that you are using `$order_id`, while it is not defined

```php
$ritiro_sede = get_post_meta( $order_id, 'ritiro_sede', true );
```

This problem is now automatically solved by the adjustment from step 1

---

So to answer your question, you get:

```
function my_custom_checkout_field_display_order_data_ritiro_sede( $order_id ) {
    // Get an instance of the WC_Order object
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    
    // Get meta
    $ritiro_sede = $order->get_meta('ritiro_sede');
    
    // Compare
    if ( $ritiro_sede == 1 ) {
        echo '<p><strong>Ritiro In sede: </strong> <span style="color:green;">SI</span></p>';
    } else {
        echo '<p><strong>Ritiro In sede: </strong> <span style="color:red;">NO</span></p>';
    }       
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'my_custom_checkout_field_display_order_data_ritiro_sede', 10, 1 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_view_order', 'my_custom_checkout_field_display_order_data_ritiro_sede', 10, 1 );
```